# Getting a Public IP that is different for my Ubuntu Server then my Homenetwork

Tags: networking, server, ip

Okay so here's the thing, I live in Sweden and got fiber with a internet speed of 100/100 mb/s. They way my network is setup right now is that I got a modem which is hooked up to my router which goes to all the computers in the house. But here's the problem, I don't want my server to have the same Public IP as my other computers in my house.

I've achived this before by using another old router i got and hooking it into the modem which got 10 ports, and this gave me a different Public IP. This would work perfectly for me if it wasn't that the router is pretty bad so it slows down the speed of the internet with a great amount.

So my guesses are to do something like to put my Server directly into the modem and not use any router at all and use some sort of program on the Server, or use some kind of setting on my router (asus RT-AC66U).

Those are my guesses but I really don't know how to do it, so any help would be really nice! But if there isn't any way of doing this I could get another router, but I don't feel like spending extra money on a router good enough to handle 100/100 mb/s.

If there are any more info that I forgot needed please point it out in the comments! Thanks!

Comment: IPv4 or IPv6? The IP is usually allocated to and assigned to you by your ISP. You can consider yourself lucky to have a public IP at all, especially if it's an IPv4. What exactly is the problem that you want to solve? Is it something like your "server" offering a website but others in your home network supposed to do the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modem already has a switch in it (since it has 10 ports). So you can plug the server directly into it and (if your ISP is giving out public IPs like that) it should get and IP just like your router would. The only reason to have a router is for the extra layer of security that it offers.

Comment: Yeah for some reason I just blocked that option out of my brain, thanks. I tried it and it works great, but would the security be a problem as the Server would be open for public use. (A minecraft server)

Comment: It depends what you're running on the server but it would definitely lower your security. Router does NATing by default so it keeps ALL ports on your computer unaccessible, without it all open ports are well open so someone can try to exploit it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want both your server and your router (with the rest of your computers behind the router) to be "directly" plugged into the modem, then you don't need another router, but an ethernet switch (also called "hub" although technically a switch and a hub are different). This will be cheaper than a full-blown router, and also faster. To the modem, it will seem like both the server and the router are connected directly.

Just be sure that your modem is OK with having two devices connected; some providers allow only one device to be connected to the modem, if a second device is plugged in, it won't get an IP address.

```
+-------+        +------+        +------------+                 
|       |        |      |        |            |                 
|       |        |      +--------+server      |                 
|       |        |      |        +--- --------+                 
|modem  +--------+switch|                               +------+
|       |        |      +---+    +-----------+          |      |
|       |        |      |   |    |           |    +-----+PC    |
+-------+        +------+   |    |           +----+     |      |
                            +----+           |          +------+
                                 | router    |                  
                                 |           +----+     +------+
                                 +----++-----+    |     |      |
                                      ++          +-----+      |
                                                        | PC   |
                                                        +------+
```

Comment: What will the switch help with? I thought switches just splits 1 Ethernet cable to multiple ones, would it actually be able to give the server its own IP? If not I don't see the need for it because of the 10 Ethernet ports I already have on my modem.